# How to debug HANA XSJS using eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hana-xs

Can some please help me how to add debugger to eclipse for debuffing xsjs file? I looked into lot of blogs but no success.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the [official guide](https://help.sap.com/doc/fbb802faa34440b39a5b6e3814c6d3b5/2.0.01/en-US/SAP_HANA_Developer_Guide_for_SAP_HANA_Studio_en.pdf) ?

Comment: Yeah but no success.

Comment: Haven't tried with Eclipse, but it works with Intellij IDEA. I have heard that Eclipse has some plugins, don't they help?